# RStoolbox::readMeta open Landsat MTL in R: Error in CRS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, error, landsat-8

I am trying to read a Landsat8 `MTL.txt` in R using `readMeta()` but I have this error:

```
meta2021 <- readMeta("C:/Users/LC08_L2SP_028028_20210305_20210312_02_T1_MTL.txt")

Error in CRS(paste0(c("+proj=", "+zone=", "+units=m +datum="), pars, collapse = " ")) : 
  No spaces permitted in PROJ4 argument-value pairs: +proj= +zone= +units=m +datum=
```

Comment: What package does `readMeta` come from? Can you also tell us where to get a metadata file like that?

Comment: is it RStoolbox::readMeta and can I get a MTL file from the S3 browser: https://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html ?

Comment: Works for me for an MTL picked randomly from the S3 data so might be something to do with that specific one (or more). Looks like it doesn't have proper "PROJECTION PARAMETERS" section. Point us to that file or we're pretty much relying on guesswork.

Comment: you can dowload it on the https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ website. I have the same problem with different MTL file of different locations. Landsat collection 2 - level 2 / Landsat 8 OLI. thanks

Comment: How can I pass to you the file? Many thanks

Comment: Any file sharing service - Box, OneDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive - upload, make public, share link.

Comment: here it is: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oaVmEAyu50qMPrATxsmCLSmpDdXZoSdV?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MTL file has:

```
  GROUP = LEVEL1_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
    MAP_PROJECTION = "UTM"
    DATUM = "WGS84"
    ELLIPSOID = "WGS84"
    UTM_ZONE = 15
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_PANCHROMATIC = 15.00
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_REFLECTIVE = 30.00
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_THERMAL = 30.00
    ORIENTATION = "NORTH_UP"
    RESAMPLING_OPTION = "CUBIC_CONVOLUTION"
  END_GROUP = LEVEL1_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
```

but other ones have:

```
  GROUP = PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
    MAP_PROJECTION = "UTM"
    DATUM = "WGS84"
    ELLIPSOID = "WGS84"
    UTM_ZONE = 27
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_PANCHROMATIC = 15.00
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_REFLECTIVE = 30.00
    GRID_CELL_SIZE_THERMAL = 30.00
    ORIENTATION = "NORTH_UP"
    RESAMPLING_OPTION = "CUBIC_CONVOLUTION"
  END_GROUP = PROJECTION_PARAMETERS
```

which is the same data but with a different GROUP name, so `readMeta` doesn't find it. I don't know if `readMeta` is intended to work with these particular metadata files, or maybe you should file a bug report with RStoolbox.

You can use `raw=TRUE` to read the data into a list and then extract any bits you need:

```
> m = readMeta("./LC08_L2SP_028028_20210305_20210312_02_T1_MTL.txt",raw=TRUE)

> names(m)
 [1] "PRODUCT_CONTENTS"                     
 [2] "IMAGE_ATTRIBUTES"                     
 [3] "PROJECTION_ATTRIBUTES"                
 [4] "LEVEL2_PROCESSING_RECORD"             
 [5] "LEVEL2_SURFACE_REFLECTANCE_PARAMETERS"
 [6] "LEVEL2_SURFACE_TEMPERATURE_PARAMETERS"
 [7] "LEVEL1_PROCESSING_RECORD"             
 [8] "LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_RADIANCE"              
 [9] "LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_REFLECTANCE"           
[10] "LEVEL1_MIN_MAX_PIXEL_VALUE"           
[11] "LEVEL1_RADIOMETRIC_RESCALING"         
[12] "LEVEL1_THERMAL_CONSTANTS"             
[13] "LEVEL1_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS"
```

I don't know why the projection info appears twice:

```
> m$PROJECTION_ATTRIBUTES["UTM_ZONE",]
[1] "15"
> m$LEVEL1_PROJECTION_PARAMETERS["UTM_ZONE",]
[1] "15"
```